# \paragraph as subsubsubsection in \figure centering

Tags: floats, sectioning, paragraphs

I use the \paragraph as a subsubsubsection in my document of report type and when I try to put the title of the section on the same page by including it in the figure, it's center it's self because of the comand centering. How do I exclude the paragraph?

```
\subsubsection{Conception détaillée}
\begin{figure}[H]
\paragraph{Schéma du circuit}\mbox{}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{P3/Sommateur/SommateurPondéré.png}
    \caption{Sommateur pondéré}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why don't you move `\paragraph` before `\begin{figure}`?

Comment: you have added `\centering` within the paragraph started by `\mbox`  place a blank line before it  so it only affects following paragraphs. (and also move it out of figure)

Comment: You may also try to replace \centering by \begin{center} \end{center}

Comment: `\begin{center} \end{center} `work thanks a lot!